# Heap Corruption on member assignment overload?

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

(Clarity Update)

Have been struggling with this problem for a while and would like some insight. I have overloaded the `addition` and `assignment` operators for a created class. The `assignment` operator seems to return fine, but then the next line exits with this error:

> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#160) at 0x012CA7D0. CRT
>   detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap
>   buffer.

My code for both operators are below:

```
HSString& HSString::operator =(const HSString& argStr) {

    if (this != &argStr) {
        delete[] str;
        end = argStr.end;
        cap = argStr.cap;

        if (end > 0) {
            str = new char[end];
            for (int i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
                str[i] = argStr.str[i];
            }
       }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

//Default Constructor

```
HSString::HSString() {

    cap = 20;

    end = 0;

    str = '\0';

    createdCount++;

    currentCount++;
}
```

//Destructor

```
HSString::~HSString() {

    delete[] str;

    currentCount--;
}
```

//Copy Constructor

```
HSString::HSString(const HSString& argStr) {

    cap = argStr.cap;

    end = argStr.end;

    if (end > 0) {
        str = new char[end];

        for (int i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
            str[i] = argStr.str[i];
        }

    } else {
        str = nullptr;
    }

    createdCount++;

    currentCount++;
}


const HSString HSString::operator +(const HSString& strOne)const {

    HSString temp;

    temp.end = end + strOne.end;
    temp.cap = cap + strOne.cap;

    temp.str = new char[cap];

    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        temp.str[i] = str[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= strOne.end; i++) {
        temp.str[i + end] = strOne.str[i];
    }

    return temp;
}
```

After member assignment operator is returned with a deep copy the error is then executed.

I go one past the end of a string to include the null terminator to clean up extra garbage values in dynamically created memory.

Using Rule of Three concepts.

//Sample:

```
int main() {

HSString greeting("Hello");
HSString name("Hayden");
HSString result;
```

vvvvvv //Heap Corruption happens right after this statement is executed vvvvvvv

```
result = greeting + name;


cout << result;





system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to post a [mcve], since I can see multiple issues with just the small sample you posted.  Your `str` is not set to nullptr if `end <= 0`, thus if your destructor attempts to do `delete [] str;`, the behavior becomes undefined.  Also for `operator +` to work correctly requires us to see your copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor, not just a snippet of one of those functions.

Comment: I did update my example with a bit more information. Thanks I'm new to the community and am just learning the post guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

`for (int i = 0; i <= end; i++)`

This creates an overflow. Because in C++ arrays start at Index 0 if your declare an array with 5 elements the index range is from 0 to 4. So if you create an array of size `end` your Indexes range from 0 to end - 1. That means you need to check for `i < end`

EDIT:
this propably applies to `for (int i = 0; i <= strOne.end; i++)` too despite i do not know the implementation of `HSString`

Comment: Updated my code to provide more implementation information. I go one over the labeled end to include the null terminator on strings.

Comment: @HaydenSmith You only allocated `end` elements, not `end + 1` elements.  Thus there is no room for the null terminator.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie epic nice. I was forgetting to allocate the correct amount of memory for that null terminator. forgot it took up memory space. thanks again.